# Crouton min API level Issues

Tags: android, crouton

I'm trying to use the library but there's this line in Manager.java (line 215)

```
croutonView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
```

that I don't understand how to fix. Eclipse says

```
Call requires API level 16 (current min is 4): android.view.ViewTreeObserver#removeOnGlobalLayoutListener
```

I don't think I can just simply change the current min API level to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="16" />

instead of 

 <uses-sdk 
      android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: It fixes the error but now I can't use the library in my app.

Comment: Crouton currently works until API level 4. There's no need to exclude devices running an Android version lower than 16.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to compile against `android:targetSdkVersion="16"` or greater.

The ViewTreeObserver  [call will only be made for Jelly Bean](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton/blob/master/library/src/de/keyboardsurfer/android/widget/crouton/Manager.java#L212) and up in Version 1.8.1.

Comment: I don't know how but I think I fixed it by adding the support library. minSDKVersion is still set to 4 in the Crouton manifest.